# Different result after final render

Tags: rendering

I have model and with preview render and final render result are totally different.

[image]

Preview (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) render

[image]

Final render <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

The pipe color totally change. Any suggestion or help. Why im getting this result.

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong but I applied the curve and screw modifier then applied scale and it renders fine after that. So its something to do with the modifier at render time. Although i didnt see anything that would change in the render.

Comment: @icYou520 yeah i have notice but i want to know the reason without applying the modifier why im getting different result.